# Saving dynamically added text box to database

Tags: django, django-views

First here is my view:

```
def price_save(request):
    remarks = request.POST.get("remarks")
    current_user = request.user
    pah = PAH(remarks=remarks, created_by=current_user)
    pah.save()

    item1 = request.POST.getlist("item_code[]")
    item2 = request.POST.getlist("item_description[]")
    item3 = request.POST.getlist("uom[]")
    
    for item in item1:
        item_price = PAR(transaction_id=pah, item_code=item, item_description=item2, uom=item3)
        item_price.save()
    
    return HttpResponse("Saved!")
```

with this I can save multiple rows with different values on item_code and same transaction id, but I dont know how to add item_description and uom in the for loop.

Comment: what do you mean by you don't know?  You have added them in your view

Comment: Yes I have added them in my view but the item_description and uom is saved like this: ['Waterpik WP-360 Cordless Traveller', 'Waterpik WP-450 Cordless Plus'] not per row.